# Buffered queue for logging

Tags: c#, beginner, async-await, producer-consumer

I'd like to use a buffered queue for logging via a WebAPI that handles multiple applications. This helper should reduce the blocking that occures due to logging.  I've been experimenting with a producer/consumer pattern and the `BufferedProcessor<T>` is what I've come up with. Internally it uses the `BlockingCollection` and allows the user (me) to specify the handler action - it's going to be `HttpClient.SendAsync` (with additional processing) used as fire-and-forget. Although currently its main purpose is to be used for logging I may use it in other scenarios too.

```
public class BufferedProcessor<T> : Task
{
    private const int Unlimited = -1;

    private static readonly TimeSpan Indefinite = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1);

    private readonly State _processor;

    public BufferedProcessor(Action<T> process)
        : this(process, Unlimited, CancellationToken.None)
    { }

    public BufferedProcessor(Action<T> process, int bufferSize)
        : this(process, bufferSize, CancellationToken.None)
    { }

    public BufferedProcessor(Action<T> process, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        : this(process, Unlimited, cancellationToken)
    { }

    public BufferedProcessor(Action<T> process, int bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        : base(Start, new State(process, bufferSize, cancellationToken), cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
    {
        _processor = (State)AsyncState;
    }   

    public bool Enqueue(T obj)
    {
        return Enqueue(obj, Indefinite);
    }

    public bool Enqueue(T obj, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        return _processor.Enqueue(obj, timeout);
    }

    private static void Start(object state)
    {
        ((State)state).ProcessObjects();
    }

    private class State
    {
        private readonly Action<T> _action;

        private readonly BlockingCollection<T> _queue = new BlockingCollection<T>();

        private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken;

        public State(Action<T> action, int bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _action = action;
            _queue = bufferSize > 0 ? new BlockingCollection<T>(bufferSize) : new BlockingCollection<T>();
            _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
        }

        public bool Enqueue(T obj, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            return _queue.TryAdd(obj, timeout);
        }

        public void ProcessObjects()
        {
            foreach (var obj in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(_cancellationToken))
            {
                _action(obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I've tested it. I created three produces working with different speeds and limited the queue to 3 items. Before leaving the application I'm waiting for items that may still be in the queue.

```
void Main()
{
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    Console.WriteLine($"Main ThreadId = {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

    var processor = new BufferedProcessor<int>(
        i => Console.WriteLine($"{i.ToString().PadLeft(3, '_')}\tThreadId = {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"),
        3,
        cancellationToken);

    processor.Start();

    var producer1 = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
        {
            processor.Enqueue(i);
            await Task.Delay(200);
        }
    });

    var producer2 = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(10, 10))
        {
            processor.Enqueue(i);
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    });

    var producer3 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(100, 10))
        {
            processor.Enqueue(i);
        }
    });

    Task.WaitAny(producer1, producer2, producer3);

    // Wait for logs in queue before exiting the application.
    Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { processor }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
}
```

Does this design have any *obvious* weaknesses? I've added the [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) tag because I have very little experience with all the `async` stuff.

Comment: I have change the implementation so the `BufferedProcessor<T>` is now derived from `Task`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any obvious problems. I'm not a fan of extending `Task` though. It has enough responsibilities as-is, IMHO. Original implementation that used aggregation instead of inheritance  was more straightforward and easier to understand. It took me a while to figure out how `BufferedProcessor` and `State` interact with each other, pretty confusing.

P.S. This type of consumer already exists in [Dataflow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library):

```
var processor = new ActionBlock<int>(n => Console.WriteLine(n),
                                     new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions 
                                     {
                                         BoundedCapacity = 3,
                                         CancellationToken = cancellationToken 
                                     });
processor.Post(1);
processor.Post(2);
```

You can grab it from NuGet, unless you intentionally reinvent this stuff.

Comment: oh, I didn't want to reinvent it :) next move: reading about the dataflow components.

Comment: @t3chb0t, yeah, for some reason this library is not well known, even though it easily solves all typical data-processing tasks. Probably because it is not included it TPL and goes as separate package.

Comment: I noticed an important difference between my implementation and using the `ActionBlock`, the latter calls the delegate in new threads whereas mine was using the same thread for each call - but as I've said, I wasn't quite sure what I was doing ;-) I think it's not widely known because the naming convention in the dataflow package is very unusual. Everything is called a _block_ etc so it rarely pops up in search results. It could have been better, I guess.

Comment: I'm taking it back about the unusal naming... I'm reading through the docs and this is pretty cool, I now get why they are called blocks ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions` allows you to set the degree of parallelism. If you set it to `1`, actions will still execute on threadpool (probably), but they should no longer run in parallel.